# Zabbix upgrade from 4.0.21 to 5.2 mysqlversion error

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, monitoring, zabbix, ubuntu-20.04

Good morning Dear.

I am having a problem updating my Zabbix server. Currently I have running the zabbix server version "zabbix_server (Zabbix) 4.0.21" with Ubuntu 16.04 xenial.

I want to update it to zabbix server 5.2 with Ubuntu 20.04 focal.

I installed in a new virtual server with Ubuntu 20.04 focla and I had no problems except for the version of the zabbix database, it has the following version:

mysql> select * from dbversion;

- ----------- + ---------- +
  | mandatory | optional |
- ----------- + ---------- +
  | 4010004 | 4010004 |
- ----------- + ---------- +
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)

I would need to update at least to version 5020000, does anyone know how I can make this update?

From already thank you very much.

Greetings.

Comment: did you read https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/installation/upgrade/packages/debian_ubuntu ?

Comment: I have read and followed that instruction, but at no point does it talk about the version of the database and that is what is ending up giving an error.The installation in a new server I do it perfectly, I copy the configuration files and others. But the problem happens when I export the database.
This is the message I get when starting the Zabbix service after exporting the database.
 current database version (mandatory / optional): 04010004/04010004
 starting automatic database upgrade
 database upgrade failed

Comment: `database upgrade failed` needs to be investigated in logs, there's usually also another error message indicating why the upgrade failed.

Comment: The Zabbix database version does not match current requirements. Your database version: 4010004. Required version: 5020000. Please contact your system administrator. That is de unic error

Comment: zabbix highlighted some known issue. Please have a look on this link
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/installation/known_issues

Comment: The problem was solved by upgrading zabbix 4.1 to 5.0 and then running an update / upgrade. After this the BD version was automatically updated and you can update to Zabbix 5.2. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `/usr/share/zabbix/conf/zabbix.conf.php and /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf` with the password..

Also run below commands :

To upgrade `Zabbix` minor version please run:

```
$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade 'zabbix.*'
To upgrade Zabbix server minor version please run:
$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade 'zabbix-server.*'
To upgrade Zabbix agent minor version please run:
$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade 'zabbix-agent.*'
```